# How can I run user code securely in nodejs using VM without being vulnerable to attacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a nodejs project, and I want to be able to run user code safely using the `vm` module, but there's many vulnerabilities such as the `constructor` of every object/function to be used to eval js string. any way to secure it? Thanks!

I tried everything, but nothing works. I also don't want to use other packages. Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions in this space. Though it may be very obvious to you (and to someone else after carefully reading your question), it would still be useful to others if you indicated clearly how your question differs from the others, or how their answers were insufficient for your question. Ex. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7446729/20170164), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11028666/20170164), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73236354/20170164), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17513212/20170164). That's one way you can demonstrate your on-site research effort.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any built-in method to run untrusted code safely. I suppose if you could work with external libraries, there are a few solutions dedicated to this purpose like [isolated-vm](https://github.com/laverdet/isolated-vm) and [vm2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2).